# Joining two rows of single table with all duplicate value except one?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have googled so much however I haven't found any appropriate solution. I am developer and don't have a deep knowledge of sql queries. Please help me.

This table is generated by LEFT JOIN of two table user & location with foreign key location_id.

[getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvx8x.png)

Now I want it to be something like below..

[expecting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Fcy.png)

Comment: your query code please

Comment: I would be helpful to post your database tables so that we can try and help you with the query.

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a maximum of just two addresses for a user then you could try subqueries like this:

```
SELECT 
  u.user_id,
  u.full_name,
  u.user_type, 
  (SELECT name FROM location WHERE id=u.location_id LIMIT 1) location,
  (SELECT name FROM location WHERE id=u.location_id LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) location_something
FROM user u
...
```

If only one address is found, *location_something* would be null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about the number of locations, then I don't think we can get the 'expecting result' with SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have left join result in #SomeTable

Your can select result like

```
SELECT 
  user_id, full_name, user_type,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + [location] 
    FROM #SomeTable
    WHERE (user_id = Results.user_id) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS Locations
FROM #SomeTable Results
GROUP BY user_id, full_name, user_type
```

and than somewhere further in your code you split "Locations" column in each row